# If you do something on keyup, make sure you got the associated keydown first

Tags: bug, user-experience

Sometimes on a Windows machine, your focus and attention get stolen by a program presenting a dialog, or you hit the Windows key on your keyboard by accident, causing the Start menu to overlap what you were doing.

The OS allowing this has ingrained a reflex with me: I hit the <kbd>Esc</kbd> button to close such annoyances.

This behavior has caused me to curse at the Jira (issue tracking software) website for more than I want to admit: halfway entering an issue details and hitting <kbd>Esc</kbd> because something popped up on my screen causes the site to close the entry form popup and you to lose all entered data.

And so does Stack Overflow's comment box.

*"But why"*, you'll ask, *"do you press Esc then, if you don't want your data to be lost?"*. Well, I do if I want, but that's not always the case when it happens.

The issue is, here as well as with Jira, the site responds to the Esc key **UP** event, without verifying that it previously also received the key **DOWN** event.

So when I press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to close a dialog, or the Start menu, they close - but the key is still pressed. Upon releasing it, it cancels my input on the website. The latter should only happen when the site had the focus when I pressed the key, not only when I release it when the site has focus.

Repro (on Windows, in Chrome):

1. Post a comment on a Stack Overflow post
2. Start editing this comment
3. Press the Windows key
4. Press the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key
5. See the changes to your comment disappear, as `cancel` is issued

This occurs in multiple situations, the snippet editor [has got the same problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404856/user-setting-to-allow-disable-esc-key-on-snippet-editor-it-causes-an-infinite-p).

Comment: I had the same problem forever... Good thing you can remap the Windows key on Linux.

Comment: With firefox on Ubuntu it looks like there is a bit of a delay in the Esc key after the window key. If I just click it, it doesn't cancel the edit. I have to keep it pressed down for several seconds in order for it to also cancel the comment edit.

Comment: In a better world, we would have an event that triggers only after seeing a keydown-and-keyup pair, to make it so that the path of least resistance for hotkeys is to implement them in exactly the way you would like them to be implemented here rather than the way that they in fact have been implemented. Alas, we don't live in that world, and the event that sounds a bit like it ought to do that - `keypress` - really does something different that's almost identical to `keydown`.

Comment: It will be changed. In 6-8 [unit unspecified].

Comment: This kind of mess is why I disabled keyboard shortcuts. Web applications rarely implement them in a way that's less annoying than just using standard browser functionality. More often than not, they just get in the way.

Comment: No repro... or perhaps I misunderstand. If you activate the Start menu (or any other dialog), and then press Esc, the dialog that you're dismissing will "eat" the Esc key press. It won't get passed on to the web browser. The web browser doesn't have focus because the Start menu or other dialog has the focus. Also, it is very standard to respond to the key *up* event, rather than the key *down* event, because that allows you the possibility of canceling your action as long as you change your mind before you release the key.

Comment: @CodyGray how do you change your mind? Change focus before releasing the key?

Comment: Also: ESC does not cancel comment creation, but it does cancel editing of older comment. But is doesn't repro. At least not in FF 68 on win7. I did experience this problem with JIRA though. Apparently it is a FF thing, as other browsers behave differently (they don't send the ESC to the web page).

Comment: Here is a similar problem: in a comment  type @ followed by a few letters that match several other commenters. Select one by cursor keys and press enter, result: the comment is submitted, even if you only wanted to select a user for replying.

Comment: This is probably already posted here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66646/176236

Comment: Indeed! One needs to actually save the comment before editing it @Cody. Then, I was able to reproduce the esc pressed for the windows key also closing the editing comment dialog.

Comment: Posting a comment for testing... EDIT: Can repro. Now I'm annoyed even though this has never affected me.

Comment: @CodyGray Except it doesn't eat the event, at least on Windows 10 with Chrome. I can replicate the OP's issue.

Comment: @DavidBalažic IKR. It took me frickin ages to realise you press _tab_ instead of _enter_ to select it. I'm sure for Linux users this is intuitive, but as a Windows user who never tab-completed anything before I started work at my current job, it never occurred to me that tab might be used to confirm a selection.

Comment: Holding the ESC key and not releasing it has the same effect on unsaved comments. Testing in an edit now to see the difference. EDIT - Yeah, for me it appears worse on a new, unsaved comment, but even then it only happens if I hold the ESC key for a few seconds after dismissing the start menu.

Comment: Repro for comment editing with FF on Win 10. Note that the question editor behaves differently (there, you need to hold down `Esc` for a while but don't even have to release it).

Comment: Good find. A GUI equivalent of this would be pressing the mouse button, **then** moving the pointer over a GUI button, and releasing, and having the button activate.

Comment: There's really three things going on here with the keyboard:  The key _press_, the key _repeat_, then the key _release_.  One possible sequence is that the dialog or start menu sees the _press_, you hold the key down and the focus changes to your browser, then the key _repeats_ (which will look like a _press_ to to browser), then you _release_ the key and the current browser action is canceled.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Key presses repeat. Key up and down are lower level events that occur once per physical action.

Comment: @TKK But does that lower level distinction make its way to the higher level apps?  It is common enough to handle key down and key repeat events identically (like in a command prompt, where you get multiple copies of the key that is repeating).

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Apparently JS, at least, works the way you suggested.

Comment: You can easily reproduce this by hitting edit on this question, then opening something else on top e.g. via the Windows key, and pressing Escape. The edit will then be cancelled. – I agree that this is certainly a confusing behavior. Using the keyup event in general _is_ better than just using the keydown event (ideally, you would check the sequence as OP suggests), so maybe the solution here would be to prompt for discarding unsaved changes when there are changes.