# User setting to allow disable Esc key on snippet editor? It causes an infinite popup loop

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets, editor, popup

When I'm writing code on my editor and I need to skip or close [IntelliSense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_code_completion#IntelliSense) suggestions, I press the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key in order to keep writing freely. So, I've got this habit of writing some stuff and automatically pressing the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key at some points, because I know that [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code) is going to autosuggest some options and I want to close them and keep writing.

But when I'm writing in the Code Snippet editor here on Stack Overflow and I press the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key by the force of habit (which happens quite often), I get stuck in **this infinite popup loop**. Because pressing the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key again does not get you out of the popup. It reappears immediately. So I've got to grab the mouse and click on "Cancel"

Could this be fixed somehow? Maybe add a user setting option where you could disable the <kbd>Esc</kbd> behavior when the snippet editor is opened?

[image]

Browser: Chrome 88 
Windows 10

Comment: _Because pressing the Esc key again does not get you out of the popup_ It does seem to get me out of popup in firefox

Comment: @SurajRao Sorry I didn't mention that. I'm using Chrome Desktop 88 on Windows 10.

Comment: I have a userscript that [incidentally fixes this](https://github.com/CertainPerformance/Stack-Exchange-Userscripts/blob/master/Stack-Snippet-Userscripts/Find/StackSnippetFind.user.js) by disabling the Esc key entirely.