# Teams invitation popup disappears when releasing mouse cursor outside popup

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-for-teams

In your free Team, under Users, you can invite users by email address by clicking "Invite users", which shows a popup:

> [image: Popup]

Now you see, someone sent me their email address over IM, and the IM client helpfully prepended "mailto:" in front of it, which I'm pretty sure the form won't accept, so I want to remove it. So I positioned my mouse cursor before the "f" of "foo", and dragged my mouse wayyy to the left to select all text before it (being the "mailto:" part), after which I intended to hit either backspace or delete, wherever one of my fingers was closest to at that moment:

> [image: Popup with selected text]

(*That black thingy circled in red is my attempt at drawing a mouse cursor, which Windows' Snip & Sketch doesn't include in screenshots*.)

See it in action, courtesy of [Oleg Valter](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/11407695/oleg-valter):

> [image: Animation]

Now when you release the mouse button outside that popup, the popup disappears, sending your input (including the mailto:) to /dev/null. The same happens when drag-selecting *any* text on that dialog, for example the title.

That should not be happening. See also [If you do something on keyup, make sure you got the associated keydown first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387220/if-you-do-something-on-keyup-make-sure-you-got-the-associated-keydown-first).

Comment: Maybe they don't like your drawing skills :) To be more serious, here is a recording of the same phenomenon, feel free to use: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJVSF.gif

Comment: NP - btw, used a screencasting program I was recommended a while ago, in case you don't know it - ScreenToGif, an amazing thing to work with.